# Per module provider configuration

Tags: angularjs, ng-idle

Is it possible to configure providers with different values per module?

I am using [ng-idle](http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/) and would like to configure timeout for each module differently.

```
angular.module('module1').config(function($idleProvider){
   $idleProvider.warningDuration(5);
});

angular.module('module2').config(function($idleProvider){
   $idleProvider.warningDuration(10);
});
```

But module loaded first overrides the configuration.

Comment: Services are singleton in nature, so the configuration changes are global. Unless the service itself support such configuration, you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i can work around by catching event, increasing counter and restarting it... or modify plugin.